# Creating DateTime from timestamp in PHP < 5.3

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, php-5.2

How do you create a DateTime from timestamp in versions less than < 5.3?

In 5.3 it would be:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $timeStamp);
```

The DateTime constructor wants a string, but this didn't work for me

```
$date = new DateTime("@$timeStamp");
```

Comment: According to the manual, that should work.  Have you tried `$date = new DateTime('@' . $timeStamp);` ?  And by "didn't work", what do you mean?

Comment: Define *didn't work for me*. Errors? Wrong date/time?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (@) at position 0 (@): Unexpected character'

Comment: @Jonah, I tried your method- same error

Comment: @Yarin: It's giving you that error because the timestamp is empty.  Find out why.

Comment: What does `var_dump($timeStamp)` give you?

Answer (score 46):

PHP 5 >= 5.3.0

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($timeStamp);
```

**Edit:** Added correct PHP version for `setTimestamp`

Comment: Think this is PHP 5 >= 5.3

Comment: This answer is incorect, setTimestamp() added in php 5.3

Answer (score 32):

Assuming you want the date and the time and not just the date as in the previous answer:

```
$dtStr = date("c", $timeStamp);
$date = new DateTime($dtStr);
```

Seems pretty silly to have to do that though.

Comment: This solution works, but unnecessarily spends time formatting the date string, then re-parsing.

Answer (score 15):

It's not working because your $timeStamp variable is empty.  Try echoing the value of $timeStamp right before creating the DateTime and you'll see.  If you run this:

```
new DateTime('@2345234');
```

You don't get an error.  However, if you run:

```
new DateTime('@');
```

It produces the exact error you said it gives you.  You'll need to do some debugging and find out why $timeStamp is empty.

Comment: Be warned, that using `@` in the constructor will ignore the environment's current timezone and the timezone when supplied in the second argument., even when using `$dateTime->modify('@' . 1234)` use `setTimezone(date_default_timezone_get())` to change from the UTC timezone to the environment timezone.

Comment: I had this same problem when I used '@' with an empty timestamp, thanks for this answer.  The error message PHP gave was less than helpful, it implied the '@' was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The following works:

```
$dateString = date('Ymd', $timeStamp);
$date = new DateTime($dateString);
```

Comment: Timestamp[1] is not just Ymd, it's number of seconds(micro seconds in some cases) since 1st Jan 1970 UTC.

[1] = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: May be `$dateString = date('U', $timeStamp);` then?!