# how to format hours in php?

Tags: php, format, hour

I made this function and it works:

```
$myHour = "09:09";
$myHour = time_format($myHour);
      function time_format($h){   
            $initial_string = $h;
            $new = substr($h,1,strlen($h));
            $h = substr($h,0,-4);
            if ($h == "0"){
                return $new;
            }else{
                return $initial_string;
            }
        }
```

This function verify it the string looks like: "01:02" and get rid of the first "0", so it will become "1:02" else if it looks like "13:13" it will return "13:13".
My question is how to improve my function? or if there exists other better method ? thx

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: There's almost certainly a better method: where is $h coming from?

Comment: $myhour = time_format($myhour);   // $myhours looks like "04:00" for example

Comment: OK, so where's $myhour coming from?

Comment: check now my post again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will be your shortened function, still readable

```
function time_format($h){
    if (substr($h, 0, 1) == "0"){
        return substr($h, 1);
    }else{
        return $h;
    }
}
```

this would be even shorter

```
function time_format($h){
    return substr($h, 0, 1) == "0" ? substr($h, 1) : $h;
}
```

this one is even without the if operators

to read more about it, here is a [link](http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples).

Answer (score 2):

use ltrim to just simply remove the leading 0 if there is one.  I assume there is a reason you cant just change the date format which generates the string ?

```
 function time_format($h){   
       return ltrim($h, "0");
 }
```

But changing the date format is the best option

Comment: I rewrite my function : function time_format($h){   // se scoate primul "0 " din ora a.i 01:21 devine 1:21
  $initial_string = $h;
  $h = substr($h,0,-4);
  if ($h == "0"){
    return ltrim($initial_string, "0");
  }
  return $initial_string;
 }

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Please have a detailed look here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

You can get a DateTime object by UnixTimestamp (if needed) with this way

```
$dtStr = date("c", $timeStamp);
$date = new DateTime($dtStr);
```

Source: [Creating DateTime from timestamp in PHP < 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329872/creating-datetime-from-timestamp-in-php-5-3)

Comment: I dont have days year, etc, I have hours and minutes , for instace 34:42 (34 hours and 42 minutes). The problem occurs when i have "09:05" I want to get rid of the first "0" so the result should be 9:05 (9 hours and 5 minutes)

Comment: then it is `new DateTime('34:42:00')`. Please Read the Manual. (I dont know if it works with more then 24 hours, can't test it now). If not use `setTime()`

Answer (score -2):

[use PHP date function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

try to google first..